# Creating index for large table is taking forever

Tags: sql-server-2012, performance, index

I am trying to create Index for a large table with row count of 496,000,000 and the database is on SQL Server 2012  Enterprise edition. I know how to create index but its taking forever and would like know how to make it faster? Here is the script i tried.

```
create clustered index.....on table.name ([Column.name] desc)
    with (
            PAD_INDEX = off
            ,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = off
            ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = off
            ,DROP_EXISTING = off
            ,ONLINE = off
            ,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = on
            ,ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = on
            ) on [PRIMARY] 
            go
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Comment: Is there more than one way to create an index for a table? `CREATE <optional type> INDEX <name> ON <table> (<columns>)`

Comment: Generally, the best way to create an index is on columns that is repeatedly used to join or filter data.

Comment: I flagged as off-topic > too broad. Your question at hand is "how do I make this faster?" without any code that you have written. Right now, it seems to be about an idea or theory. Please post some code, even what you have tried so far to create a database. What is slow to you? What is fast?

Comment: @Hunter I have edited my question and thanks for the comment

Comment: If you don't have any indexes on the table, does that mean you don't have a primary key as well (which implies an index)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create clustered index ix1_table1 on dbo.table1 (col1) with (online = on)

This will take a little longer, the online part, but it will allow users to continues using the table while the index is being created. Every table (with very few exceptions) should have a clustered index.

Comment: i am going to use these script below - should i pass oFF for Allow_row_lock and page_Lock please?                                                                       CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ..... ON Table.Name
(
 [Column.name] DESC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: You mean the above mentioned script...

Comment: Yes, the above script.

Comment: Unless you have a good reason allow these settings to stay on leave it alone. SQL server needs to lock things during updates and deletes and you probably don't want to have table locks every time you update a row.

Comment: @Yared if this works, then please upvote it as well. You can upvote answers to your own questions at your rep level (3)